# Problem with (AttributeError) client.logs_from

Tags: discord.py

i was creating bot for discord channel. But I don't understand where i have wronged or errored in my code

I was do from tutorial but in video this wrong not present. Then I search this problem in another tutorial, but i don't have result pls help

```
@client.command(pass_context=True, name='clear', aliases=['purgemessages'], no_pm=True)
async def clear(ctx, number):
    number = int(number)
    if number > 99 or number < 1:
        await ctx.send("Sorry comrade>-< \n But i can deleted message within a range of 1 - 99")
    else:
        author = ctx.message.author
        authorID = author.id
        mgs = []
        number = int(number)
        channel = ctx.message.channel
        async for x in client.logs_from((channel), limit = int(number)):
            mgs.append
        await ctx.message.channel.delete_messages(ctx, member, mgs)
        await ctx.send("This was deleted ^^")
```

I want a bot to delete messages

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`client.purge()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge) to do it.

It seems that you're looking for a way to delete the command caller's messages (a.k.a `author`).

Here's a quick example using `purge()` method :

```py
author = ctx.message.author

# check function
def is_caller(message):
   if(message.author.id == author.id):
      return(True)
   else:
      return(False)

# delete the author's messages
# the purge method returns a list of deleted messages
deleted_message = await client.purge(
   limit = number,
   check = is_caller
)

await ctx.send(f"{len(deleted_message)} messages deleted.")
```

The limit is represented by the `number` parameter of your command.

Hope it helped !

Comment: `is_caller` should probably just return `message.author.id == author.id`.  Otherwise it returns `None` instead of `False`.

Comment: Ay ay that's correct, fixed ! 
It's a solution, but I don't really like the one-line statments